# How to artificially validate a zend form (without submit)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm trying to populate a form with data and validate it, artificially i.e. without the user actually submitting the form. So I'm creating the form and trying to fill its data using `setValue`. I'm then using `$form->isValid()` but it's asking for the form data. Since I don't have an actual Post submission, not sure how to get this data. It's already stored in the form, so why can't isValid() get the data from the form itself. Does anyone know how I could validate this form without doing an actual submit?

```
$form = new MyForm();
$form->field1->setValue('some value');
$form->field2->setValue('field2 value');
$form->field3->setValue('last field');

if($form->isValid()){
  //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `isValid`, you use

- [`valid()` to *Determine if current element/subform/display group is valid*](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Form/Zend_Form.html#valid)

Example:

```
if ($form->valid()) {
    echo 'It is valid';
}
```

If you want to use `isValid`, set and validate the form data with an associate array, e.g.

```
if ($form->isValid(array(
    'field1' => 'foo',
    'field2' => 'bar',
    …
))) {
    echo 'It is valid';
}
```